# Amazon ECS says I haven't opted in to new ARN and Resource ID format, when I clearly have

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I'm deploying a service to amazon ecs through docker. I need to assign an IAM role to the cluster that allows it to communicate with secrets manager, as that's where some of the important configuration comes from. However, when trying to select the iam role, I get this error message:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtrJh.png)

So I tried following the amazon documentation and going to the account settings tab signed in as the root account, only to find that the settings were already enabled by default. So now I'm sort of stuck as to what to do at this point. Is there something I'm missing here?

[resources already enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJPzE.png)

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot what I understand is that the IAM role you are using to deploy the container does not have "ecsInstanceRole" in your IAM roles. You could use the following steps to create it.

1. Open the IAM console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/
2. In the navigation pane, choose Roles and then choose Create role.
3. Choose the AWS service role type, and then choose Elastic Container Service.
4. Choose the EC2 Role for Elastic Container Service use case and then Next: Permissions.
5. In the Attached permissions policy section, select AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role and then choose Next: Review.
   Important
6. The AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role managed policy should be attached to the container instance IAM role, otherwise you will receive an error using the AWS Management Console to create clusters.
7. For Role name, type ecsInstanceRole and optionally you can enter a description.
8. Review your role information and then choose Create role to finish.

or you can follow the below document:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html